# How To integrate appium with robot framework?

Tags: android, appium, jython, robotframework

I want to automate an Android app through RobotFramework, can anyone help me  integrate Appium within RobotFramework.

**Note I am using RobotFramework version3.0 in jython.**

Comment: Did the answer solve your question?

Answer (score 5):

### First install Appium

Using pip

```
pip install robotframework-appiumlibrary
```

Using setup.py

```
git clone https://github.com/jollychang/robotframework-appiumlibrary.git
cd robotframework-appiumlibrary
python setup.py install
```

Using Jython

```
jython -m pip install robotframework-appiumLibrary
```

Once it is installed you will be able to see 3 directories within your RobotFramework Directory.

```
/Demo
/Doc
/Src
```

Demo proviods on example of using the software

Doc contains the Docs, holding the keyword information, similar to the  [RobotFramework UserGuide](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html).

and Src contains the code of the library

That should have it on your machine. Then within your RobotFramework testcase, Import Appium

```
Library    Appium
```

This was found at the [Git of the Library](https://github.com/serhatbolsu/robotframework-appiumlibrary)

[Keywords](http://serhatbolsu.github.io/robotframework-appiumlibrary/AppiumLibrary.html) of the library

Any questions please ask.

Comment: Goralight, is there any standalone jar for appium-robot framework inclusive of all dependencies?

Comment: @Akash, Unfortunately, I have never actually used Appium! Ill take a look for you now, but I dont exactly know what I'm looking for. Could you possibly provide a list of dependencies?